# Hover over a div and change two images with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to duplicate an old site's function as lean as possible, and I'm running into an issue with `.hover` and `.each`.  At this point, it will swap the images on mouseover, but for some reason isn't swapping back on mouseout.  I know it's something syntax-related, but as I'm getting over a cold my brain just isn't catching it.

Relevant code:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(".home-center").hover( function (){
        $("img", this).each(
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-off.png/, "-on.png"));
            },
            function() {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-on.png/, "-off.png"));
            }
        );
    });
})(jQuery);
<script>
<div class="home-center">
    <div class="home-right">
        <img class="home-icon" src="/images/homepage/home-icon-off.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="home-link">
        <img class="home-img" src="/images/homepage/home-downloads-off.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might also check this tut out ->http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leanest way to duplicate this is to use CSS, without resorting to JavaScript at all:

```
<style>
  .home-center .off {
    display: inline;
  }
  .home-center:hover .off {
    display: none;
  }
  .home-center .on {
    display: none;
  }
  .home-center:hover .on {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
<div class="home-center">
  <div class="home-right">
    <img class="home-icon off" src="/images/homepage/home-icon-off.png" />
    <img class="home-icon on" src="/images/homepage/home-icon-on.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="home-link">
    <img class="home-img off" src="/images/homepage/home-downloads-off.png" />
    <img class="home-img on" src="/images/homepage/home-downloads-on.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I did not test this so it might be wrong, but you get the idea.

I think this works in IE7+ at least, but quite possibly in IE6 or even IE5 too.

Comment: Well, that's wonderful but ultimately useless since I'm not using background images.  Issues with cross-browser compatibility and empty divs aside, the actual images in question are chosen and alt-tagged for Google Image Search, which would be completely lost with CSS.  I'm using a CSS solution to change the text inside the div, though, and really wish there were a CSS solution that would work for this.

Comment: Done. It's actually much nicer now.

Comment: I had to change to `display:inline` to work with the actual layout I've got going on (some non-cleared floats), but it works brilliantly!  Many thanks, sir!

Comment: Ah, that is, in fact, more correct, as `img` defaults to `display: inline`. My bad, and you're welcome :)

Comment: Also going to note here (for posterity) that this solution ends up being quicker than jQuery, as the images are already loaded so there's no delay on first mouseover.

Answer (score 2):

change the order to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".home-center").each(
        $(this).hover( function (){
            var img = $(this).children('img');
            function() {
                img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace(/-off.png/, "-on.png"));
            },
            function() {
                img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace(/-on.png/, "-off.png"));
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup, was going to say same thing, apply the hover event to each element. not each element to the hover event.

Comment: img.home-center? Is it correct? img.home-center would look for image with class .home-center right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. the goal is to write the appropriate selector to grab those img tags.

Comment: What If the OP wants all the images inside .home-center to turn to be -on when mouseenter and -off on mouseleave. Your solution is going to turn on hover on image, in OP post.. he was trying to hover on the div. But in his code there was only one image.. but the post says images... I am not sure if this is what he really want.

Comment: That doesn't really work, since the images don't have the `home-center` class, and because I want them to swap on div hover, not specific image hover.  In the actual code, `home-center` is about 200x200 with text as well, which is why I'm applying the hover event to the overall div.  This code is the closest I could get to a unit test.

Comment: @SKS the solution to his problem has much more to do with the order of his operations

Comment: @Kristian - After the edit, it looks like it should work, but like the other answers I'm getting a JS error `function statement requires a name` on the line after `var img = $(this).children('img');`

Answer (score 2):

`.hover` takes 2 args (mouseenter, mouseleave). You had just one arg.

Try something like below, (See my alternate solution below)

```
(function($) {
    $(".home-center").hover( 
        function () { //mouseenter
           $("img", this).each(function() {
                 $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-off.png/, "-on.png"));
            });
         },
         function () { //mouseleave
            $("img", this).each(function() {
                  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-on.png/, "-off.png"));
            });
         }
    );
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively I would just implement `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` to simply the number of selector calls.

```
(function($) {
     $("img", ".home-center").mouseenter(
           function () { //mouseenter
               $(this).each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-off.png/, "-on.png"));
                });
           })
           .mouseleave(function () { //mouseleave
                $(this).each(
                   function() {
                     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-on.png/, "-off.png"));
                });
             }
         );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The first example throws an error of `function statement requires a name` on the line after `$('img', this).each(`, the second example only works hovering over the images, not the containing div.

Comment: @SickHippie There was a error in the first function.. Fixed now.. Try now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Had to take out one of the `}`, but it does work.  I ended up going with Thomas' straight CSS solution, though - it has the added benefit of no delay on first mouseover, as the images are already loaded.  I'm going to file this one away for later use, though - thanks for your help!

Comment: @SickHippie Agreed. Definitely CSS based solution are better. Thanks for trying out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the each inside the functions.. or outside the hover. Right now you're only supplying hover with one argument (the each) for mouse over, and nothing for mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

Close! Looks like a nesting problem. It's `hover` that takes two arguments, not `each`:

```
(function($) {
$(".home-center").hover( function (){
    $("img", this).each(
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-off.png/, "-on.png"));
        }
    ),
    $("img", this).each(
        function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/-on.png/, "-off.png"));
        }
    );
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, but it actually does nothing at all...  Not quite sure why, either.